# I want to know why the two outputs are different

Tags: c++, mysql, c

I use c++ to connect mysql to complete some operation,this is parts of my code.

```
const char* deleteLog_query = DeleteLog(userIDstr).c_str();
cout<<deleteLog_query<<endl;
const char* deleteReplyOfLog_query = DeleteReplyOfLog(userIDstr).c_str();
mysql_query(&mysql_conn,deleteReplyOfLog_query);
mysql_result = mysql_store_result(&mysql_conn);
const char* deleteShareOfLog_query = DeleteShareOfLog(userIDstr).c_str();
mysql_query(&mysql_conn,deleteShareOfLog_query);
mysql_result = mysql_store_result(&mysql_conn);

cout<<deleteLog_query<<endl;
mysql_query(&mysql_conn,deleteLog_query);
mysql_result = mysql_store_result(&mysql_conn);
if(mysql_result!=0) cout<<"\t right delete!"<<endl;
```

this is output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Lets take for example this line:

```
const char* deleteLog_query = DeleteLog(userIDstr).c_str();
```

Lets say that the `DeleteLog` function returns a string object by value, then the returned object is a temporary object that will be destructed once the expression `DeleteLog(userIDstr).c_str()` is finished. That means the pointer that is returned will now point to a string that no longer exist, and dereferencing that pointer will lead to *undefined behavior*.

If, on the other hand, `DeleteLog` returns a reference to a string object, then if it's a reference to a non-static local variable you have a similar but equally bad scenario. Local non-static variables in a function goes out of scope when the function ends, and references to such variables are no longer valid and using them will also lead to *undefined behavior*.

So what is the solution to your problem? Well if it's the second problem (returning references to non-static local objects) you need to make it return the string by value. That gives us the first problem, which is solved by you not saving pointers to temporary object and instead using proper `std::string` objects, and use `c_str()` when actually needed (e.g. in the actual call to `mysql_query`).